# CKEditor 5 set style on Element

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

we are trying to "hack" CKEditor 5 font-family a bit. We would like set `font-style` to parent element (for example `<p>`), when you select whole text in element. Resulting syntax would be much cleaner instead of unnecessary `<span>` tag inside `<p>`

But when trying to `setAttribute` on `Element` it doesn't work, however the attribute is set in Model. But resulting text is unchanged. Also we haven't found `addStyle` method on `Element`

Here is our current modification of `fontcommand.js` (note line with `if(range.start.isAtStart && range.end.isAtEnd){`):

```
model.change( writer => {
            if ( selection.isCollapsed ) {
                if ( value ) {
                    writer.setSelectionAttribute( this.attributeKey, value );
                } else {
                    writer.removeSelectionAttribute( this.attributeKey );
                }
            } else {
                const ranges = model.schema.getValidRanges( selection.getRanges(), this.attributeKey );

                for ( const range of ranges ) {
                    if ( value ) {
                        if(range.start.isAtStart && range.end.isAtEnd){
                            writer.setAttribute( this.attributeKey, value, range.start.parent );
                        } else {
                            writer.setAttribute( this.attributeKey, value, range );
                        }
                    } else {
                        writer.removeAttribute( this.attributeKey, range );
                    }
                }
            }
        } );
```

Having `<p>something</p>` we would like to get `<p style="font-family: Arial">something</p>` when choosing font-style.

Anyone willing to give us a hint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Quick answer

The amount of work needed to implement this in a reliable way (taken all possible scenarios how and to what a font family can be applied) is not worth the cleaner output.

### Long answer

First, you need to understand how the [editor's model](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/editing-engine.html#model) work. That it's an abstract representation of the rich-text content (in which you won't find styles, just generic attributes) which is later converted to a [DOM-like view](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/editing-engine.html#view).

So, answering why the font family style wasn't rendered in the DOM despite the fact that you changed some attribute in the model – that's because you haven't provided [converters](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/editing-engine.html#conversion) for that attribute. By default, the font plugin provides only a converter for a [text attribute](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/editing-engine.html#text-attributes) (yep, in the model inline styles are represented as text attributes).

Now, let's consider you provided the right converters. What's now?

The user applies a font family to the entire paragraph – so you change this attribute on that paragraph. It gets rendered as `<p style=...>`.

But then, the user changes the font family on part of the text in that paragraph. If you won't do something, you'll end up with:

```
<p style="font-family:x">foo <span style="font-family:y">bar</span></p>
```

And soon you may have this:

```
<p style="font-family:x"><span style="font-family:y">bar</span></p>
```

Not any more a cleaner output, right?

So, what you'd need to do is to [watch all the changes in the model](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_model-Model.html#function-change) and, at some point, remove this attribute from the paragraph. There's actually even a concept of [post-fixers](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_document-Document.html#function-registerPostFixer) which can be used for such a job. But it gets complicated, isn't it?

The other option is to use the fact that conversion (between the model and the view) in CKEditor 5 is something really powerful. You should be able to convert model's text attribute to (conditionally):

- a view element's attribute if this attribute is present on the entire content of this element;
- or using the default converters (which create `<span>`s on the text).

Where's the code? I'm too lazy to write it. And test it. This improvement is, IMO, not worth the effort.

**EDIT:** Sorry for the tone of the last sentence, but that's how I feel about tweaking such things. As developers we tend to be pedantic, but from data perspective it doesn't make much difference (in this case).