# Angular CKEditor 5 add custom class on button click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to add class to selected element (table in this case) when clicking button on element toolbar.

```
       const dropdownView = createDropdown(locale);
        const model = editor.model;

        dropdownView.buttonView.set({
            label: "Table Style",
            icon: icon,
            tooltip: false
        });

        const items = new Collection();
        items.add({
            type: "button",
            model: new Model({
                id: "type1",
                withText: true,
                label: "Type 1"
            })
        });
        items.add({
            type: "button",
            model: new Model({
                id: "type2",
                withText: true,
                label: "Type 2"
            })
        });
        addListToDropdown(dropdownView, items);

        dropdownView.on("execute", function (eventInfo) {
            const type = eventInfo.source.id;
            model.enqueueChange("default", (writer) => {
                const selection = model.document.selection;
                const table = selection.getFirstPosition().findAncestor("table");

               // this not working. It works with keys like: height, width, but not with class
                writer.setAttribute("class", type, table);
            });
        });
```

Can not add custom attributes. How can I add class or dataset attribute?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `type` string you're passing into `setAttribute()` is one of the expected values "type1" or "type2"?

Comment: The values are as expected "type1" and "type2"

Comment: Shooting in the dark here because I'm not familiar with CKEditor... but maybe this [`addClass`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_writer-Writer.html#function-addClass) method would work. It's accessed through [`editor.view.change()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_view-View.html#function-change) instead of `editor.model.change()/enqueueChange()`. Not sure if that's a problem or not.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50762288/4028303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found:

```
    const editor = this.editor;

    const comid = "tableClassAttribute";

    editor.model.schema.extend("table", { allowAttributes: comid });

    editor.ui.componentFactory.add("tableClass", (locale) => {
        const dropdownView = createDropdown(locale);
        const model = editor.model;

        dropdownView.buttonView.set({
            label: "Table Style",
            icon,
            tooltip: false
        });

        const items = new Collection();

        tableClasses.forEach((tableClass) => {
            items.add({
                type: "button",
                model: new Model({
                    id: tableClass.id,
                    withText: true,
                    label: tableClass.label
                })
            });
        });

        addListToDropdown(dropdownView, items);

        editor.conversion.attributeToAttribute({
            model: {
                name: "table",
                key: comid
            },
            view: {
                name: "figure",
                key: "class"
            }
        });

        dropdownView.on("execute", function (eventInfo) {
            model.enqueueChange("default", (writer) => {
                const type = eventInfo.source.id;
                const selection = model.document.selection;
                const table = selection.getFirstPosition().findAncestor("table");
                writer.setAttribute(comid, "table-" + type, table);
            });
        });

        return dropdownView;
    });
```